# How do I change priority of firefox address bar suggestions to tags?

Tags: firefox, tags, address-bar

I have a heavily tagged bookmark collection, and searching it by tags is much more relevant  than by url, title or history. 
Is there a way to make tags a priority, so when I type in address bar, I get matching tags first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Location_Bar_search

You can restrict what kind of results are shown in the drop down list by using customizable characters.
Include the character anywhere in the address bar separated by spaces to have it restrict what results are displayed.
The characters are as follows:

```
Preference names in about:config    default key     action
browser.urlbar.match.title  #   Returns results that match the text in the title.
browser.urlbar.match.url    @   Returns results that match the text in the URL.
browser.urlbar.restrict.bookmark    *   Returns only results that are from the bookmarks.
browser.urlbar.restrict.history     ^   Returns only results that are from the browser’s history.
browser.urlbar.restrict.tag     +   Returns only results that have been tagged.
browser.urlbar.restrict.typed   ~   Returns only results that have been typed.
browser.urlbar.restrict.openpage    %   Returns only open tabs (visible tabs, not active tab), available in Firefox 4 (SeaMonkey 2.1) and later
```

Also see browser.urlbar.default.behavior to customize your normal Auto Complete (AwesomeBar) search behavior at the Location Bar. Normal is to search on text strings, but can be changed to require word boundaries.

This will let you search by tags, at least, instead of openly searching everything. Using `* tag` will search bookmarks by both name AND tag, although it doesn't seem to matter which order the results for that up in. `+ tag` will list all results for a tag.

Comment: This helps a lot. Still, it is not that I always remember exactly that I have used a string as a tag previously, so prioritizing would be a better solution.. But I guess there is no way to do it yet, so your answer is accepted.

Comment: Helped me after 8 years, so...  Perfect!